# Filter get_the_title to remove certain characters?

Tags: php, filters, title, get-the-title

I know that WordPress can filter shortcodes like `the_content` but is it possible to filter `get_the_content`?

I have a function that is able to use `substr` and `strpos` and I know it works on `the_title`. I tried the same thing for `get_the_title` but I couldn't get it to work.

Is it possible for the same to work on `get_the_title`?

Code I have so far:

```
function gg_short_title($title) {
// This can return false, so check there is something
$linkt=array();
$linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#8212;'));
$linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#8211;'));
$linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#124;'));
$linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' -'));
$short_title = implode('', $linkt);
if ($short_title) {
    return $short_title;
}

// Else just return the normal title
return $title; 
} 
add_filter('get_the_title', 'gg_short_title', 10, 1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the title input and expected output? It looks like you're trying to do something with a title containing an em dash, en dash, vertical bar, or a regular dash.

Comment: Title before: AMD reveals Radeon Pro 400 series GPU specs, as used in new MacBook Pro | Ars Technica
Title after: AMD reveals Radeon Pro 400 series GPU specs, as used in new MacBook Pro

Comment: Yep. Didn't work `$linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#8212;'));
 $linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#8211;'));
 $linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &#124;'));
 $linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' -'));
 $linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' &mdash;'));
 $linkt[] = substr($title, 0, strpos($title, ' |'));`

Comment: Thx. Did you also try matching against HTML all entities (e.g. `&mdash;`, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) is just a wrapper around the function [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

It's understandably confusing that the filter `the_title` actually exists inside `get_the_title()`. So, whatever the function you're using to actually display it, it doesn't matter, you can filter its content by hooking into `the_title`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to moraleida's answer, here's a shorter way to match and output your titles.

**Note** - It will split the string on the first match it finds so if there are multiple '|' or 'em dash' characters, that could be a problem (even for your original code).

```
function gg_short_title( $title ) {

  if ( 1 === preg_match( '(&#8212;|&#8211;|&#124;|-|\|)', $title, $matches ) ) {
    $short_title = explode( $matches[0], $title, 2 );
    $title = trim( $short_title[0] );
  }

  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'gg_short_title', 10, 1 );
```